# how how properties of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

can someone please help me with some code to count properties of an array, so i have an array and i want to count all the complete items the have the value 1. here is my array

```
[{
    "order_id": "336566",
    "customer_name": "joel",
    "customer_surname": "kabeya",
    "total_items": "0",
    "completed_items": "0",
    "percent_complete": 1,
    "datetime_received": "2019-01-21 15:00:27",
    "delivery_date": "2019-01-24",
    "delivery_from": "10:30",
    "delivery_to": "12:00",
    "completed": "1",
    "shopper": "joel"
}, {
    "order_id": "335719",
    "customer_name": "joel",
    "customer_surname": "kabeya",
    "total_items": "0",
    "completed_items": "0",
    "percent_complete": 1,
    "datetime_received": "2018-12-24 13:46:27",
    "delivery_date": "2018-12-30",
    "delivery_from": "10:30",
    "delivery_to": "12:00",
    "completed": "1",
    "shopper": "joel"
}, {
    "order_id": "336531",
    "customer_name": "Tay",
    "customer_surname": "Z",
    "total_items": "0",
    "completed_items": "0",
    "percent_complete": 1,
    "datetime_received": "2019-01-11 08:42:27",
    "delivery_date": "2019-01-17",
    "delivery_from": "10:30",
    "delivery_to": "12:00",
    "completed": "1",
    "shopper": "joel"
}, {
    "order_id": "336545",
    "customer_name": "joel",
    "customer_surname": "kabeya",
    "total_items": "0",
    "completed_items": "0",
    "percent_complete": 1,
    "datetime_received": "2019-01-17 19:00:27",
    "delivery_date": "2019-01-18",
    "delivery_from": "11:00",
    "delivery_to": "12:00",
    "completed": "0",
    "shopper": "joel"
}, {
    "order_id": "241918",
    "customer_name": "Marietjie",
    "customer_surname": "Short",
    "total_items": "44",
    "completed_items": "44",
    "percent_complete": 1,
    "datetime_received": "2018-07-25 15:18:25",
    "delivery_date": "2018-10-29",
    "delivery_from": "12:00",
    "delivery_to": "13:00",
    "completed": "0",
    "shopper": "Tay"
}, {
    "order_id": "281774",
    "customer_name": "Ashleigh",
    "customer_surname": "Hodge",
    "total_items": "16",
    "completed_items": "0",
    "percent_complete": 0,
    "datetime_received": "2018-10-04 15:59:19",
    "delivery_date": "2018-10-29",
    "delivery_from": "12:00",
    "delivery_to": "13:00",
    "completed": "0",
    "shopper": null
}]
```

Comment: Start with `Array.reduce()` and come back with an attempt.  Or even `Array.filter(somfilterfunction).length;`

Comment: @egalvan10 It's in the tags.

Comment: You can also use a `for` loop, or the `forEach()` function. Both of them just increment a counter whenever the object matches the criteria.

Comment: @egalvan10 i'm using javascript

Comment: What do you mean by `count all the complete items the have the value 1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leverage [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and use the `length` property of `Array`.  Bear in mind that your completion criteria is that `completed` is the `String` value `"1"`.  So filter based on that predicate, then count the items left.

```js
const yourPileOfData = [{
    completed: "1"
  },
  {
    completed: "1"
  },
  {
    completed: "0"
  }
];

const count = yourPileOfData.filter(i => i.completed === "1").length;

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `foreach` loop to iterate and add. Also `filter` can be used.

```
//foreach
```

The `foreach` loop loops through every element and checks if the object has the completed property set to 1. If it is one the counter is incremented and returned. Otherwise the counter is returned as is.

```
//filter
```

Filter also loops through the elements one by one and if they satisfy the condition`(completed==1)` it returns true and send the element to a new array whose length we print. If it returns false, the value is not inserted inside the array.

```js
var a=[{
    "order_id": "336566",
    "customer_name": "joel",
    "customer_surname": "kabeya",
    "total_items": "0",
    "completed_items": "0",
    "percent_complete": 1,
    "datetime_received": "2019-01-21 15:00:27",
    "delivery_date": "2019-01-24",
    "delivery_from": "10:30",
    "delivery_to": "12:00",
    "completed": "1",
    "shopper": "joel"
}, {
    "order_id": "335719",
    "customer_name": "joel",
    "customer_surname": "kabeya",
    "total_items": "0",
    "completed_items": "0",
    "percent_complete": 1,
    "datetime_received": "2018-12-24 13:46:27",
    "delivery_date": "2018-12-30",
    "delivery_from": "10:30",
    "delivery_to": "12:00",
    "completed": "1",
    "shopper": "joel"
}, {
    "order_id": "336531",
    "customer_name": "Tay",
    "customer_surname": "Z",
    "total_items": "0",
    "completed_items": "0",
    "percent_complete": 1,
    "datetime_received": "2019-01-11 08:42:27",
    "delivery_date": "2019-01-17",
    "delivery_from": "10:30",
    "delivery_to": "12:00",
    "completed": "1",
    "shopper": "joel"
}, {
    "order_id": "336545",
    "customer_name": "joel",
    "customer_surname": "kabeya",
    "total_items": "0",
    "completed_items": "0",
    "percent_complete": 1,
    "datetime_received": "2019-01-17 19:00:27",
    "delivery_date": "2019-01-18",
    "delivery_from": "11:00",
    "delivery_to": "12:00",
    "completed": "0",
    "shopper": "joel"
}, {
    "order_id": "241918",
    "customer_name": "Marietjie",
    "customer_surname": "Short",
    "total_items": "44",
    "completed_items": "44",
    "percent_complete": 1,
    "datetime_received": "2018-07-25 15:18:25",
    "delivery_date": "2018-10-29",
    "delivery_from": "12:00",
    "delivery_to": "13:00",
    "completed": "0",
    "shopper": "Tay"
}, {
    "order_id": "281774",
    "customer_name": "Ashleigh",
    "customer_surname": "Hodge",
    "total_items": "16",
    "completed_items": "0",
    "percent_complete": 0,
    "datetime_received": "2018-10-04 15:59:19",
    "delivery_date": "2018-10-29",
    "delivery_from": "12:00",
    "delivery_to": "13:00",
    "completed": "0",
    "shopper": null
}]
var count=0;
a.forEach((e)=>e.completed=="1"?count++:count)
console.log(count);
//filter
console.log(a.filter((e)=>e.completed=="1"?true:false).length)
```